# How can I determine when an expression is evaluated?

Tags: performance, haskell, lazy-evaluation

I've recently been learning haskell, and I understand the concept of lazy evaluation in general. One thing that I've discovered though is that it's often difficult to reason about exactly when an expression will be evaluated.

Is there a good way for getting information about precisely what is going on in terms of evaluation? Ideally I'd like to see something like a stack trace or a dependency list that shows when an expression needed to be evaluated, and what other expressions it depended on had to be evaluated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See here for an example of [GHCi debugger](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.2/html/users_guide/ghci-debugger.html) session.

Comment: That seems to be what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility is to use [Debug.Trace](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Debugging) facility.

Comment: Does Debug.Trace force evaluation of something that might otherwise not be evaluated?

Comment: Only if your trace expression forces the evaluation of something. If you trace something with no variables, like just a pure string (i.e. trace "hi"), then, never.

Answer (score 0):

with the lazyness an expression is really evaluated if his value is needed in the rest of the code. In some situation you can have a program which not access to any elements of the data structure just because in your program you haven't use them :

```
import System.Environment    

-- this first version of the foo function evaluate a list (reversing) but don't use it any more
-- the result show that nothing is compute even the reverse du to the haskell lazyness
foo :: [a] -> IO ()
foo [] = print ("empty list")
foo xs = do let xs' = reverse xs in print ("reversable list")

-- this function evaluate the reversed list's length, so the compiler is oblige here to evaluate
-- both reverse and length
foo' :: [a] -> IO ()
foo' [] = print ("empty list")
foo' xs = do let xs' = reverse xs in print ("reversable list of size " ++ show (length xs'))    

main = do 
    [arg1, arg2] <- getArgs
    let listSize = read arg1
    let prog     = read arg2 
    if prog == 0 then foo (replicate listSize 'e') else foo' (replicate listSize 'e')
```

Execution results show the following time execution

```
./stack1 100000000 0  -- calling the foo function with 100000000 elements
"reversable list"

real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.004s
sys  0m0.000s

time ./stack1 0 0 -- calling the foo function with an empty list
"empty list"

real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.004s
sys  0m0.004s
```

we observe that we have the same execution time. let try with **foo'**

```
time ./stack1 0 1 -- calling foo' with an empty list
"empty list"

real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.004s
sys  0m0.000s

time ./stack1 100000000 2
"reversable list of size 100000000"

real    0m8.662s -- here 8 minutes are spend to reverse and get the list length
user    0m7.944s
sys  0m0.716s
```